# Unable to specify lifetime parameter to solve compilation error

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm learning Rust by doing small stuffs. I'm currently writing this app so, its first step is to read a `config.json` file, but I'm having this compilation error that I'm unable to resolve.

Here's my `Cargo.toml` dependencies

```
[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"
regex = "1.4.3"
```

Here's the code

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::path::Path;

use regex::Regex;
use serde_json::Value;

fn _get_config() -> Box<dyn FnMut() -> &Value> {
    let mut config = Box::new(Value::Null);
    let a = || {
        if *config == Value::Null {
            match File::open("config.json").and_then(|file| -> Result<Value, std::io::Error> {
                serde_json::from_reader(BufReader::new(file)).map_err(|e| e.into())
            }) {
                Ok(v) => *config = v,
                Err(_) => {
                    *config = serde_json::from_str(
                        r#"
                            {
                                "DOMAIN_AS_ROOT_FOLDER": false,
                                "secret": "abcxyz"
                            }
                        "#,
                    )
                    .expect("Cannot initialize config, abort !");
                }
            }
        }
        config.as_ref()
    };
    Box::new(a)
}

fn main() {
    let get_config = _get_config();
    get_config();
}
```

And here's the compilation error

```
❯ cargo run
   
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:9:40
  |
9 | fn _get_config() -> Box<dyn FnMut() -> &Value> {
  |                                        ^ expected named lifetime parameter
  |
  = help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but there is no value for it to be borrowed from
  = note: for more information on higher-ranked polymorphism, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html
help: consider making the bound lifetime-generic with a new `'a` lifetime
  |
9 | fn _get_config() -> Box<dyn for<'a> FnMut() -> &'a Value> {
  |                             ^^^^^^^            ^^^
help: consider using the `'static` lifetime
  |
9 | fn _get_config() -> Box<dyn FnMut() -> &'static Value> {
  |                                        ^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0106`.
error: could not compile `sieve_generator`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Basically the `_get_config()` returns a closure that allows me to get the `config` object everytime I call it. I don't see why there is such error since the variable `config` is supposed to live as long as my closure, there's nothing else as parameters here, why does it requires a lifetime here ? And how do I fix it ?

Thank you all very much for your time. I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: I don't have all of those libraries installed, so I can't test this easily, but it looks like you may need to [`move`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.move.html) your variable into the closure, as right now `config` is getting dropped at the end of `_get_config`, hence the error.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. It doesn't change the error if I move it. But from what I know I thought that the environment doesn't drop as long as the closure exist ? And for the libs just adding it to `Cargo.toml` is enough

Comment: Yeah, but what guarantee does the compiler have that the closure will not go out of scope at some point during the applications lifetime? If the closure goes out of scope at any point during your applications life time `&Value` will become a dangling pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll never be able to do what you want as you can't guarantee to the compiler that the closure will **NEVER** go out of scope for the applications life time (which you'd have to do in this case because the compiler has no idea how long you'll hold on to the `&Value` reference).

Instead, since it looks like you're reading the configuration from disk only once why not store it in a static variable with the help of the [lazy_static](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static) crate.

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;
use serde_json::Value;
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

lazy_static! {
    static ref CONFIG: Arc<Mutex<Value>> = {
        let file: std::io::Result<Value> = File::open( "config.json" ).and_then( | f | { 
            serde_json::from_reader( BufReader::new( f ) )
                .map_err( | e | e.into( ) )
        } );
        Arc::new( Mutex::new( match file {
            Ok( v ) => v,
            _ => { 
                serde_json::from_str( 
                    r#"
                    {
                        "DOMAIN_AS_ROOT_FOLDER": false,
                        "secret": "abcxyz"
                    }
                    "#
                 )
                .expect( "Cannot initialize config, abort !" )
            }
        } ) )
    };
}

fn main( ) {
    let config = CONFIG.lock( ).unwrap( );
    // Use your config here.
}
```

EDIT:

The `Arc` and `Mutex` are only necessary if you plan on mutating the `Value`. If you are not going to mutate the configuration at some point then you can ditch the use the of `Arc` and `Mutex`.

In both examples I removed the `Option` type as it wasn't needed.

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref CONFIG: Value = {
        let file: std::io::Result<Value> = File::open( "config.json" ).and_then( | f | { 
            serde_json::from_reader( BufReader::new( f ) )
                .map_err( | e | e.into( ) )
        } );
        match file {
            Ok( v ) => v,
            _ => { 
                serde_json::from_str( 
                    r#"
                    {
                        "DOMAIN_AS_ROOT_FOLDER": false,
                        "secret": "abcxyz"
                    }
                    "#
                 )
                .expect( "Cannot initialize config, abort !" )
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. As you probably know, I've been coding in JS/TS heavily the past years so the code above is some sort of JS/TS coding style with closure. I guess I gotta drop some of those habits.

Comment: @Quoc-HaoTran I updated the answer. If you're not planning on mutating the configuration then the `Arc` and `Mutex` are not required.